# chkdsk Corrupt master file table

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, filesystem-corruption

I booted up my computer and i when into recovery mode on further inspection running

```
chkdsk C: /f
```

gave the following error

```
Corrupt master file table
```

and was unable to recover or even write to the event log

I next tried to refresh (or reinstall if need be) windows and the utility said the drive was locked. to solve this i tried this command

```
bootrec /RebuildBcd
```

however this gave the following output

```
Total identified Windows installations: 0
```

how can i fix my corrupted hard drive

Answer (score 0):

I searched around for this before due to an issue at work and I found the link that helped fix this issue for me. You may have to use a couple more commands before using `bootrec /RebuildBcd` to fix the `Windows is locked` issue. Also, because you have a `corrupt master file` error this may not work since **sometimes** that can represent a physical problem with the drive but it's worth a try because like I said, I had the same issue before which was on  my colleagues computer at work when we applied updates for some third-party applications we use (very odd).

**Quick Side Note**: You can check the integrity of your Hard Drive using `chkdisk C: /f /x /r` (Probably would be useful to add the extra info you receive on the output just incase my answer doesn't work for you or I could maybe improve it better with more information)

Enter these commands in order:

1) - `bootrec /FixMbr`

2) - `bootrec /FixBoot`

3) - `bootrec /Scan0s`

4) - `bootrec /RebuildBcd`

[Source](https://neosmart.net/wiki/the-drive-where-windows-is-installed-is-locked/) for these steps which also includes various other methods.